# Registration DropdownList in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I'm try to make a Year dropdownlist menu, and I have this function in my Controller:

```
// Year DropDownList
        private void GetYears()
        {
            List<int> Years = new List<int>();
            DateTime startYear = DateTime.Now;
            while (startYear.Year <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(3).Year)
            {
                Years.Add(startYear.Year);
                startYear = startYear.AddYears(1);
            }
            ViewBag.Years = Years;
        }
```

And when I try to pull in View I get get message:  An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation. The error is here: Model=> Model.Year.

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("Years", new SelectList(ViewBag.Years as System.Collections.IEnumerable, Model.Year))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Year)
</div>
```

Where I made mistake ??

Comment: Its just `@Html.DropDownList("Years", new SelectList(ViewBag.Years))`, but this is bad practice - your `ViewBag` property should not be the same name as the property your binding to. And you can simply use `ViewBag.Years = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Today.Year, 3);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViewBag is Dynamic, hence the error. 
The quickest thing would be to just cast it to a List in the view like

```
@{
 var years = (List<int>)ViewBag.Years;
}
```

and then  update to

```
  @Html.DropDownList("Years", new SelectList(years, Model.Year))
```

You could also attach the List of years as a property of the Model and then you wouldn't have to worry about casting it.